# How to call an AlertDialog when Navigator.push move to another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

What I want to do is to have for the user first time reach the screen that oine alertDialog appears.
I use this code to move to another screen:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IfProfilePage()));
```

in this specific case i switch tyo IfProfilPage but what I want is to get in IfProfilePage for the first time an alertdialog which I will build later, but this dialogf will contains some information that user has to follow.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass it in initstate method
it has to be a `stateful` widget

```
class DestinationPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DestinationPageState createState() => _DestinationPageState();
}

class _DestinationPageState extends State<DestinationPage> {
@override
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      showAlertdialog(context);
    });
  }
```

and here is a example of alert dialog that you can use

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () { },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("My title"),
    content: Text("This is my message."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: this one you write me is the destination page right? it doesnt work

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Test Alert"),
      content: Text("Here is the Alert Dialog"),
    );

    super.initState();
  }

Comment: this is what I put into a destination page

Comment: did you override the initstate in IfProfilePage() page?

Comment: please do that and tell me the result

Comment: Yeah now works fine. do you know how to show that just for 1 time?

Comment: you can do that with `shared_prefrences` read about it here https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences ,,,,